How to create custom code base like JustMyCode for test code
is it possible to create a custom code base like JustMyCode? With JustMyCode we are testing our production code (test code is discarded by a notmycode query).
Now we want to have something like JustMyATCode as a base for cheking our SpecFlow acceptance test assemblies. The rules are different or at least not as restrictive as for the production code. At the moment we have something like this in every rule:
warnif count > 0
from t in Application.Assemblies
 .Where(a => a.NameLike("AcceptanceTest.*"))
...

But this becomes cumbersome with increasing number of rules.
